# How do you parse specific values in from a txt file?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm working on an assignment in Java that requires me to read in values from a .txt file in order to tell the program what to execute.

```
Example:
/*
script.txt contains the following

decreaseKey(2, 35)
delete(p)
*/

// What I have tried doing so far:

int p = Integer.parseInt(inputLine.substring(7)); // doesnt work if p is larger then a single       char
int p = Integer.parseInt(inputLine.substring(12, 14)); // too specific, if value was 238792 it wouldn't work.
```

Also the tricky part I found was for decreaseKey I need to parse 2 different values and by doing that I did the same thing for int p twice and passed it into my function... Which obviously won't work in this case.

Any suggestions as to how I can properly parse each instruction in script.txt so that the values in my program will always match what is being passed in the txt file would be great!

Comment: You could perhaps start by parsing the commands depending on the position of brackets and not depending on hard-coded positions and afterwards deciding how much arguments you have to parse for a command.

Comment: what output you need from your script.txt?

Answer (score 0):

This will be an amount of work - you'll need to more formally define what the language is that you're parsing.

Assuming that it's a very simple grammar I'd start by running a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) over the file and observe what it finds and how I might tweak it to get something that does what I want.

If what you need is more complex, look to middleware to help you, such as the compiler of useful parsers - [cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and you may find this code based on **regex pattern matcher** useful:

```
    final String str = "decreaseKey(2, 35)";

    final String normalized = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    System.out.println(normalized);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("decreaseKey\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(normalized);
    System.out.println("matches="+matcher.matches());

    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```